# Avoiding duplicate OFFSET calculations

Tags: excel, excel-formula

How can I use the results of a single OFFSET() in multiple cells?

I have a worksheet with many rows.  For each row, there is an contiguous set of columns that I'm interested in.  The range of columns I'm interested in depends on some cells set elsewhere; I can use the OFFSET() function to define the range.

For each row, I need to call several array functions (SUM, AVERAGE, etc) on the same array reference.

This can be done by calling OFFSET in each case... SUM(OFFSET(args)), AVERAGE(OFFSET(args)); but I'm finding errors as I try to keep all of the OFFSET calls in sync with the latest definitions of the array.

Is there a way that I can turn

```
B1: =SUM(OFFSET(args))
C1: =MAX(OFFSET(args))
```

into

```
A1: =OFFSET(args)
B1: =SUM(A1)
C1: =MAX(A1)
```

or the equivalent, so that I can change the definition of the reference in one place and apply it to all of the functions in the row?

Comment: Are the columns different (or potentially different) for each row or are you looking at the same columns all the way down?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Reading your example it occurs to me this is a perfect time to employ a named formula.  CTRL-F3 to open the name wizard, create a name like ***MyRange*** and in the REFERSTO: section, enter the *OFFSET()* formula you were putting in A1.  Be sure to make it an absolute referenced formula.

Then you should be able to sum the resulting range you created with

A1: **=SUM(MyRange)**

B1: **=MAX(MyRange)**

Comment: Agreed. My answer was too complicated. This is much easier.

Comment: Trying to make sure that I follow this solution - are you suggesting one named formula per row?  Does that solution scale?

Comment: Ah - I think I see it.  There's going to be a single name, which will REFERSTO the one offset formula I've been copying everywhere.  The OFFSET formula will have the same general form - fixed column references (so that I can use the same variable name in any column), and relative row references (so that we end up with the cell range that is correct for the current row).

Care required: the relative references shown in the Define Name dialog are going to be relative to the currently selected cell (cell range) in the worksheet.  Selecting the right starting cell will make things easier.

Comment: Perfectly analyzed! That is correct.  If you select the correct "base cell" before entering a **named formula** with some *relative* references in it, it will adapt nicely as you use it in each row of that column.  A very useful technique, too.

Answer (score 1):

You could build your range address using the `Address` function, and then use `Indirect` to reference that range. For example, in A1 suppose you enter: `=ADDRESS(5,2,1,1)&":"&ADDRESS(5,3,1,1)`. That will give you an address of $B$5:$C$5. Now, you can use a formula such as `=SUM(INDIRECT(A1))` to get the sum of the values in that range.

You didn't give enough detail, so I don't know if your use of `Offset` will fit into this scheme. If you can calculate the beginning and ending rows and columns then you may be able to replace `Offset` with `Address` and `Indirect`. You can probably work it in somehow, but I don't have enough info to help with that.

Answer (score 0):

You could use an OFFSET array-entered formula to generate the correct set of columns for each row, starting in a consistent column to the right of the source table (or on another sheet if necessary) and working to the right. Then you could use the same range in all your other formulas in cells B1, C1 etc.

If you sometimes need to select different numbers of columns, you would need to add some error handling to prevent possible #N/A errors from contaminating your calculations. This can be done via IF combined with ISERROR or ERROR.TYPE.